# What is an oAuth domain

Tags: discussion, oauth2

What is the oAuth domain that is mentioned in the StackApps app registration form? I googled it but couldn't find a good description.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The OAuth domain name is the domain name that will be used to restrict the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter when authenticating from your application. This is done as a security precaution to prevent others from using your API key and redirecting to a domain name that does not match the one specified in the registration form.

The [API documentation page for authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) makes the following brief comment when describing the `redirect_uri` parameter:

> "**redirect_uri** - must be under an apps registered domain"

Comment: Still not that clear to me. In what way does the user or app authenticate through this domain? This has to be a domain that we control? There's no default? How does anyone provide to the API that they are affiliated with this domain?